# jQuery Tip Calculator - Formulas with Variables Based on TextArea Inputs

Tags: jquery, variables, user-input, validation, jquery-calculation

I found a few threads that were helpful, but nothing answered my question directly, so here's the specific issue:

To hone my limited jQuery skills I am creating a Split the Bill/Tip Calculator that calculates amounts on the click of a button based on the following inputs: Bill Total, Tip Percentage, Number of People.

However, nothing is happening when I click the button. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
var Total = $('.Total').val();
var Tip = $('.Tip').val();
var NumberOfPeople = $('.NumberOfPeople').val();
var AdjTotal = (((Tip/100)*Total)+Total).toFixed(2);
var Result = (AdjTotal/NumberOfPeople).toFixed(2);
if(isNaN(AdjTotal)) {
    $('.result').remove();
    $('.error').remove();
    $('.price').append('<p class="error">Please enter valid numbers into the above fields.</p>');
}
else {
    $('.error').remove();
    $('.result').remove();
    $('.price').append('<p class="result">Your total is $' + AdjTotal + ' ' + 'and each person owes: $' + Result + '.</p>');
}
});
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src='script.js'></script>
        <title>Split the Bill</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Split the Bill</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Bill Total: $
                        </td>
                        <td text-align="left">
                            <input class="Total" type="text" name="Total">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Tip Percentage: 
                        </td>
                        <td text-align="left">
                        <input class="Tip" type="text" name="Tip"> %
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Number of People: 
                        </td>
                        <td colspan=3>
                            <input class="NumberOfPeople" type="text" name="Number of People">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=4 align="right">
                            <button>Calculate</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are trying to use a class selector when really the element should be referenced by its name attribute

Comment: When you find yourself saying "nothing is happening", try inserting `console.warn('test')` messages or alerts into your code to see if they are being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var AdjTotal = (((Tip/100)*Total)+Total).toFixed(2);
```

Total is a string. You need to force it to be a number:

```
var AdjTotal = (((Tip/100)*Total)+Total/1).toFixed(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59WXX/